# Android Studio JNI C++ Cannot find declaration to go to

Tags: android, c++, c, macos, java-native-interface

I keep getting :

> Cannot find declaration to go to.

Whenever I **⌘ + Left Click** on my **C/ C++ JNI** functions.

[image]

How can I fix this? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Does your project build?

Comment: It builds and runs perfectly. There are no red code error highlights. However, **⌘ + Left Click** doesn't work. @RichardCritten

Comment: Static C++ code analysis is notoriously tricky, what with the preprocessor. So Android Studio is not doing a great job of it...